# winbase.inl missing in Windows Phone Kits

Tags: windows-phone-8, .lib

I have some native static library(say MyLib), wich includes windows.h, and I'm trying to reuse it in my WP8 app:

- I've copied lib's project file,
- renamed it (MyLibWP),
- changed platform toolset to `Windows Phone 8`
- tried to build it.

After which I'm getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Include\winbase.h(10170): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winbase.inl': No such file or directory

Kinda weird. Checked the specified folder - it does tell the truth, file is missing.
So, what is wrong with all this stuff?

Edit: tried to copy missing file to \Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Include\ manually, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall the SDK, I have `winbase.h` on my machine, at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Include`

Comment: My bad - winbase.inl is missing, not winbase.h. winbase.inl is uncluded in winbase.h. Have any ideas?